# Disable conversion of scalars to strings when deserializing with Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, numeric

I want to identify numerical values inserted without quotation marks (as strings) in JSON sent through the request body of a `POST` request:

For example, this would be the wrong JSON format as the age field does not contain quotation marks:

```
{
  "Student":{
    "Name": "John",
    "Age":  12
  }
}
```

The correct JSON format would be:

```
{
  "Student":{ 
    "Name": "John",
    "Age":  "12"
  }
}
```

In my code, I've defined the datatype of the `age` field as a `String`, hence `"12"` should be the correct input. However, no error message is thrown, even when `12` is used.

It seems Jackson automatically converts the numerical values into strings. How can I identify numerical values and return a message?

This is what I tried so far to identify these numerical values:

```
public List<Student> getMultiple(StudentDTO Student) {
    if(Student.getAge().getClass()==String.class) {
        System.out.println("Age entered correctly as String");
    } else{
        System.out.println("Please insert age value inside inverted commas");
    }
}
```

However, this is not printing `"Please insert age value inside inverted commas"` to the console when the age is inserted without quotation marks.

Comment: hint : Look into JSON Libraries such as GSON by Google.

Comment: What JSON parsing library are you using?

Comment: This is just a JSON post request to be handled through java

Comment: Inverted commas; commonly referred to as quotation marks

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Spring boot, by default it uses Jackson to parse JSON. There's no configuration option within Jackson to disable this feature, as mentioned within [this issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/796). The solution is to register a custom `JsonDeserializer` that throws an exception as soon as it encounters any other token than `JsonToken.VALUE_STRING`

```
public class StringOnlyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        if (!JsonToken.VALUE_STRING.equals(jsonParser.getCurrentToken())) {
            throw deserializationContext.wrongTokenException(jsonParser, String.class, JsonToken.VALUE_STRING, "No type conversion is allowed, string expected");
        } else {
            return jsonParser.getValueAsString();
        }
    }
}
```

If you only want to apply this to certain classes or fields, you can annotate those with the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation. For example:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = StringOnlyDeserializer.class)
    private String age;

    // TODO: Getters + Setters
}
```

Alternatively, you can register a custom Jackson module by registering a `SimpleModule` bean that automatically deserializes all strings using the `StringOnlyDeserializer`. For example:

```
@Bean
public Module customModule() {
    SimpleModule customModule = new SimpleModule();
    customModule.addDeserializer(String.class, new StringOnlyDeserializer());
    return customModule;
}
```

This is similar to [what Eugen suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55833554/1915448).

If you run your application now, and you pass an invalid age, such as `12`, `12.3` or `[12]`it will throw an exception with a message like:

```
JSON parse error: Unexpected token (VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT), expected VALUE_STRING: Not allowed to parse numbers to string; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT), expected VALUE_STRING: Not allowed to parse numbers to string\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 3, column: 9] (through reference chain: com.example.xyz.Student[\"age\"])
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, Jackson converts the scalar values to String when the target field is of `String` type. The idea is to create a custom deserializer for `String` type and comment out the conversion part:

```
package jackson.deserializer;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer;


public class CustomStringDeserializer extends StringDeserializer 
{

    public final static CustomStringDeserializer instance = new CustomStringDeserializer();

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        if (p.hasToken(JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)) {
            return p.getText();
        }
        JsonToken t = p.getCurrentToken();
        // [databind#381]
        if (t == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
            return _deserializeFromArray(p, ctxt);
        }
        // need to gracefully handle byte[] data, as base64
        if (t == JsonToken.VALUE_EMBEDDED_OBJECT) {
            Object ob = p.getEmbeddedObject();
            if (ob == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (ob instanceof byte[]) {
                return ctxt.getBase64Variant().encode((byte[]) ob, false);
            }
            // otherwise, try conversion using toString()...
            return ob.toString();
        }
        // allow coercions for other scalar types
        // 17-Jan-2018, tatu: Related to [databind#1853] avoid FIELD_NAME by ensuring it's
        //   "real" scalar
        /*if (t.isScalarValue()) {
            String text = p.getValueAsString();
            if (text != null) {
                return text;
            }
        }*/
        return (String) ctxt.handleUnexpectedToken(_valueClass, p);
    }

}
```

Now register this deserializer:

```
@Bean
public Module customStringDeserializer() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(String.class, CustomStringDeserializer.instance);
    return module;
}
```

When an integer is send and String is expected, here is the error:

> {"timestamp":"2019-04-24T15:15:58.968+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad
>   Request","message":"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of
>   `java.lang.String` out of VALUE_NUMBER_INT token; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of VALUE_NUMBER_INT
>   token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 3, column: 13]
>   (through reference chain:
>   org.hello.model.Student[\"age\"])","path":"/hello/echo"}