# Does Spring Web ignores the rule that Java is strongly typed?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Consider this code:

```
Foo{ String prop1; String prop2 }
Bar{ String prop1; int prop2 }
```

```
@GetMapping("/getFoo")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Foo>> getFoo() {
        return Mono.just(new Bar("a", 1))
                   .map(f -> new ResponseEntity(f, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

```
@Test
public void test() {
        webTestClient.get()
                     .uri("/getFoo")
                     .exchange()
                     .expectBody(Foo.class)
                     .consumeWith(f -> { assertEquals("a", f.getProp1());});
    }
```

The test works while I've never created the entity of type Foo. Java being strongly typed I would expect a cast error somewhere. I assume that Spring Web does introspection to avoid the error, but it surprises me. Is it really of feature of Spring Web ? Or do I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is coercion by the JSON serialize/deserialize process. By default Jackson (and other JSON providers) will automatically convert integers to and from Strings as part of processing the payload.

For example your Bar payload would be:

```
{
   "prop1": "a",
   "prop2": 1
}
```

And then Jackson (or your json library if you're using something else) will turn the 1 into a string for you when it is deserialized.

This can be disabled using a custom deserializer if you want that type of call to fail.

[Disable conversion of scalars to strings when deserializing with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55832004/disable-conversion-of-scalars-to-strings-when-deserializing-with-jackson)

[Disable the Number to String automatic conversion in jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56678885/disable-the-number-to-string-automatic-conversion-in-jackson)

The call you're making doesn't know anything about the underlying classes and is going to and from an intermediate format that matches based on field names.

Comment: Does this JSON serialization happen when instantiating the ResponseEntity ? If no, it's the place where I would expect to have a cast error.